# If twilio subaccount exists with twilioClient.api.accounts.each() in Nodejs

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to determine if a twilio subaccount exists, however the twilioClient.api.accounts.each() function only returns when results are found and not when no results are found. Does anyone know how to perform a count of subaccounts in twilio using nodejs?

twilioClient.api.accounts.each({
                      friendlyName: 'xx'
                    },
                        function(accounts){
                            console.log("only get here when accounts found.");
                        }
                    );

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `each` method for list resources is a convenient helper to iterate over results. If you just want to list the items, you should use `list` instead.

```
twilioClient.api.accounts.list({ friendlyName: 'xx' }, function(error, accounts){;
  if (error) { console.error(error);  returnl; }
  console.log(`There are ${accounts.length} accounts called "x"`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you philnash, I tried this technique but the accounts is null, so I guess with this subaccount API doesn't support list or something.

Comment: Apologies, I normally use the promise method of calling the API, the callback method takes an error as the first argument and the `accounts` as the second argument. I've updated my code in the answer above, try that instead